# Knex Id Column overwritten by joined table id

Tags: database, postgresql, knex.js

I have a REST API endpoint that returns an inner join recordset defined like this:

```js
const getByRecipeId = recipeId => {
  return knex("recipe_details")
    .innerJoin("jobs", "jobs.id", recipe_details.id_job")
    .where("id_recipe", recipeId)
}
```

In debug I have the following sql statement (Postgres):

```sql
select
    *
from
    "recipe_details"
inner join "jobs" on
    "jobs"."id" = "recipe_details"."id_job"
where
    "id_recipe" = 1
```

That returns this recordset

```
id|id_recipe|seq|id_job|qty_time|qty_job|id|code|description|
--|---------|---|------|--------|-------|--|----|-----------|
 1|        1| 10|     1|      10|     24| 1|job1|job descr1 |
 3|        1| 30|     2|      15|     24| 2|job2|job descr2 |
13|        1| 50|     3|      50|     15| 3|job3|job descr3 |
 2|        1| 20|     3|       5|     30| 3|job3|job descr3 |
 4|        1| 40|     3|      25|     24| 3|job3|job descr3 |
```

As you can see, there are two `id` fields, one for the `recipe_details` table and one for the `jobs` table.

The problem is that the javascript object returned by the endpoint has only one `id` property that is not of the main table but is overwritten by the last id field returned by the SQL statement.

How can I avoid this behavior?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of how node-pg driver behaves. When one joins in more columns to row, joined columns with the same column name always overwrite the earlier ones in select results.

You can workaround this by telling explicitly which columns to select for the result row.

Like:

```
knex("recipe_details")
    .select("recipe_details.*", "jobs.code", "jobs.description")
    .innerJoin("jobs", "jobs.id", recipe_details.id_job")
    .where("id_recipe", recipeId)
```

Comment: I reached the same workaround, Thank you @Mikael for the info.